# Apple Configurator's Whitelist Option (only allow specific apps) preventing making calls

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management

We use Apple Configurator to generate profiles and import them to MDM.

Suddenly after updating to iOS 10 (and using only allow the apps in the section  - whitelistedAppBundleIDs - we can't make outgoing calls. Tapping the green button is not working.

Any ideas what happened after updating to iOS 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding "com.apple.InCallService" identifier as white listed.